# Fraction inequality $|(\Delta+a)/(\Delta+b)|<\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to solve the following problem without list of cases:
Find $c=c(\varepsilon)>0$ such that, for a given $\varepsilon$,
$$
\forall \Delta \neq 0,|\Delta|<c\implies \left|\frac{\Delta+a}{\Delta+b}\right|<\varepsilon.
$$
$a$ and $b$ can be any value from $\mathbb{R}$, $a\neq b$, and $b\neq 0$.

**EDIT** added $\Delta \neq 0$. Clearly $c < |b|$, to avoid the division by $0$.

Comment: This question try to generalize the problem of finding $\delta(\varepsilon)$ for limit of a group of functions (quotient of polynomial?). $x=x_0+\Delta$, where $x_0$ is the limit point. $c$ is typically written with the greek letter $\delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't - unless $a=0$. For otherwise in particular $\Delta=0$ will lead to $\left|\frac{\Delta+a}{\Delta+b}\right|=\left|\frac ab\right|>\epsilon$ as soon as we pick $\epsilon$ small enough.

Comment: Pardon, my error, but $\Delta$ has to be different from $0$. I edit the question, otherwise I have to open a new question.

Comment: You are right, all cases lead to $a=0$, this is the point. Thank you.